# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in inject.preload.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angularjs-directive, filenotfoundexception

I have an angular file upload control where in I'm uploading multiple files  Like say I have uploaded 3 files and then I deleted one by one and saved the result.When it comes to last delete and saved the result and then I click on my left tree view menu item it redirects to logout page and I see the below error in console.

it happens only when I delete the last file.I'm not able to reproduce this in development environment but in SIT I'm facing this the below issue.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
blob:https://localhost:44300/a22159ae-e7c5-4e28-8413-42ac4e07b1fc Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND inject.preload.js
blob:https://localhost:44300/9bf3ecb3-ccba-4ad2-a13c-ff34b8c29522 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND inject.preload.js
```

After google, I have disabled the popup ad blocker in google chrome still it throwing the same error.

Comment: If you don't write details no one will help you!
what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this related to router paths and lazy-loading / pre-fetching of those?